# is 'APP' capability REQUIRED for WDA installation?

Tags: appium

I'm trying to run an appium script with a real iOS device.  I am currently getting this error:

```
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
```

Apparently this error is associated with security issues at noted [here](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver), but I've already completed that step and it's still not working. So then I thought maybe this is b/c my appium script does NOT set the 'APP' capability.  'APP' capability is of course is the full path to the application that is under test.  The appium documentation [here](https://appium.github.io/java-client/) obviously doesn't indicate which settings are required if any.  My question is will the Webdriver Agent not get installed on the device if the 'APP' capability is not set and thus throwing the error above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click on the appium app (which is in ur application folder) you are using > show package contents > search for .xcodeproj > you will see a couple of projects including web driver. Now open web driver agent Xcode project and use an apple developer account to code sign it.

If you have already done this, then please update your question with appium capabilities that you have set.